# Compare tuple values record wise

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare

I have an ordered tuple(its 2dimensional, column 0 are my endings, which I want to compare & column1 there are the complete urls), at "column"[0] I have to compare the first value with the second one, if they are the same, save the first value to other list and repeat. I want to compare every item with the following one, if they are euqal or not.

tuple:

```py
[('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Rose%2C-Micle%2C-kupfer%2C-52cm%2C-Oe-9cm/c-KAT240/a-XH0124KP', '/a-XH0124KP'), ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Rose%2C-Micle%2C-kupfer%2C-52cm%2C-Oe-9cm/c-KAT183/a-XH0124KP', '/a-XH0124KP'), ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Rose%2C-Micle%2C-kupfer%2C-52cm%2C-Oe-9cm/c-KAT173/a-XH0124KP', '/a-XH0124KP'), ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Liguster-Zweig-50cm-mit-Glitter/c-KAT184/a-XM0721', '/a-XM0721'), ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/3D-Stern-schwarz-mit-Glitter%2C-7%2C5-cm---SUPER-DEAL/c-KAT14/a-XM1633ZW', '/a-XM1633ZW'), ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Christbaumschmuck%2C-Zweige%2C-gold-30-cm----SUPER-DEAL/c-KAT14/a-XP0091', '/a-XP0091')]
```

I want to compare the productnumber extracted of the url, because every product could be possibly found in multiple urls

my sorting try:

```
sized = len(complete_links2) - 1

for index, tuple in enumerate(complete_links2):
    index = k
    k = index + 1  
    if k < sized:
        while complete_links2[index][1] == complete_links2[k][1]:
            k += 1
        if complete_links2[index][1] == complete_links2[k][1]:
            k -= 1 
        not_rep_links.append(complete_links2[index])     

complete_links3 = [a_tuple[0] for a_tuple in not_rep_links]
```

My problem is, that there are some unique links, that get also filter off, because my logic is not really good.

I also tried with set, with unpacking the tuple but idk how to continue

Comment: what do You mean by tuple since I see random letters and numbers which all start with `/a-` and those are not a tuple

Comment: those are my productIDs(you can hide the "/a-")
e.g my list is:/a-730104CE(column0), at column1 there is the productlink.

I can rewrite my question later, if it is not really clear, what I want

Comment: could You send the complete tuple? so that it is an actual tuple and it is easier to test

Comment: I edited my question, hope it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still a bit confused but is this what You want?

```
list_ = [
    ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Rose%2C-Micle%2C-kupfer%2C-52cm%2C-Oe-9cm/c-KAT240/a-XH0124KP', '/a-XH0124KP'),
    ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Rose%2C-Micle%2C-kupfer%2C-52cm%2C-Oe-9cm/c-KAT183/a-XH0124KP', '/a-XH0124KP'),
    ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Rose%2C-Micle%2C-kupfer%2C-52cm%2C-Oe-9cm/c-KAT173/a-XH0124KP', '/a-XH0124KP'),
    ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Liguster-Zweig-50cm-mit-Glitter/c-KAT184/a-XM0721', '/a-XM0721'),
    ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/3D-Stern-schwarz-mit-Glitter%2C-7%2C5-cm---SUPER-DEAL/c-KAT14/a-XM1633ZW', '/a-XM1633ZW'),
    ('https://www.topart-online.com/de/Christbaumschmuck%2C-Zweige%2C-gold-30-cm----SUPER-DEAL/c-KAT14/a-XP0091', '/a-XP0091')
]


products = []
links = []

for item in list_:
    if item[1] not in products:
        products.append(item[1])
        links.append(item[0])

print(links)
```

Comment: I copied it to my actual code and now I do have two more records. I have to elaborate tomorrow at work :)

Comment: @y.y bit confused. so is it good? or will You need improvements?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. as far as i noticed its fine for me :) I have to more links as before, so I guess we grabbed the unique ones also :)